# PostgreSQL script references hangs

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I"new to PostgreSQL and am struggling with a DDL issue. Below script "hangs" unless I remove column "keel" from table and unique constraint definitions. What may be the error ? Your input highly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE k_keel
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  nim character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  kood character(2) NOT NULL, -- Kahetäheline ISO 639 keelekood
  CONSTRAINT k_keel_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT k_keel_nim_uniq UNIQUE (nim)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE k_keel
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE k_keel TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE k_keel TO overload;
COMMENT ON COLUMN k_keel.kood IS 'Kahetäheline ISO 639 keelekood';

-- Table: ac.e_kiri

-- DROP TABLE ac.e_kiri CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE ac.e_kiri
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('ac.email_id_seq'::regclass),
  nimi character varying(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  memo TEXT
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY ac.e_kiri
    ADD CONSTRAINT "Nimi peal olema unikaalne" UNIQUE (nimi);
ALTER TABLE ac.e_kiri
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE ac.e_kiri TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE ac.e_kiri TO overload;
COMMENT ON TABLE ac.e_kiri IS 'Tüüpkirjade tabel';

-- DROP  TABLE ac.e_kiri_tekst CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE ac.e_kiri_tekst
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('ac.email_id_seq'::regclass),
  e_kiri INTEGER REFERENCES ac.e_kiri (id) NOT NULL,
  keel INTEGER REFERENCES public.k_keel (id) NOT NULL,
  subjekt text,
  sisu text
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY ac.e_kiri_tekst
    ADD CONSTRAINT "Nimi ja keel peavad olema unikaalsed" UNIQUE (e_kiri,keel);
ALTER TABLE ac.e_kiri_tekst
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE ac.e_kiri_tekst TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE ac.e_kiri_tekst TO overload;
COMMENT ON TABLE ac.e_kiri_tekst IS 'Tüüpkirja subjekt ja tekst antud keeles';
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "hangs"? One obvious thing: do you have a table `public.k_keel`? What happens if you change the first statement to `create table public.k_keel ...`? Or did you intend to create the `k_keel`  table in the `ac` schema as well?

Comment: those DDL hang or any sql statement hangs? try 'select 1;`

Comment: The public.k_keel table already exists, included in the script just for clarity. DDL seems to hang on CREATE TABLE ac.kiri_tekst statement and this can be remedified by excluding the "keel" column from it

Comment: When a query unexpectedly "hangs", 98% of the time it's waiting to acquire a lock. Adding a column which `REFERENCES` another table needs to acquire a lock on that table in order to install the foreign key trigger. Is some other process holding a lock on `k_keel`?

Comment: This might help: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring